# Access non-wordpress database from plugin

Tags: php, database, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to access a 'non-wordpress' database from a WordPress plugin that I am writing. I know that you can access the Wordpress database by using the `<?php $wpdb->query('query'); ?>` hook. I can't find anything on how to access other local databases.

So if I have another database called `zipcodes`, how would I access it? Is there a hook for it? I've done some searching and haven't seen much on this subject.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I figured out how to do this. You need to use the following:

```
$newdb = new wpdb( 'user', 'password', 'database', 'hostname' );
```

From there you can use:

```
$newdb->get_results("SELECT your query");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple php mysql connectivity

```
        <?php
        if ($con=mysqli_connect("localhost","<username>","<password>","<DB name>"))
        {           
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from tablename");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
          {
            echo $row['name'];; 
            echo $row['address'];
          }

        mysqli_close($con); 

        }
        else 
          {
          echo "<li>Failed to connect to MySQL: </li>";
          }
        ?>
```